# Why getting only day value from date in python pyplot Need help to get full date value on xaxis even though show in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

Why getting only day value from date in python pyplot. Need to get full date value on xaxis even though show in pivot table

`DFPlot_T` is Dataframe with columns - `DateValue`, `DCID`, `AUC` i.e. as below

```
      DateValue DCID       AUC
151  2021-07-08  108  0.673615
152  2021-07-09  108  0.672392
153  2021-07-10  108  0.668459
154  2021-07-11  108  0.660191
155  2021-07-12  108  0.667469
```

Data types:

- `DateValue`:    `datetime64[ns]`
- `DCID`:                 `object`
- `AUC`:                 `float32`

```
tDFPlot = DFPlot_T.pivot_table(index='DateValue', columns='DCID',values='AUC', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)
```

here pivot tables looks like this

```
 DCID             108         2         4        64         8        89
DateValue
2021-07-08  0.673615  0.706438  0.690591  0.691836  0.687345  0.691366
2021-07-09  0.672392  0.705697  0.698336  0.692887  0.689730  0.690755
2021-07-10  0.668459  0.703191  0.688982  0.692403  0.680268  0.687791
2021-07-11  0.660191  0.700091  0.694729  0.689505  0.684263  0.675027
2021-07-12  0.667469  0.707310  0.696657  0.689057  0.692796  0.690741
```

Here is the image for data above

[image]

How to resolve issue on date under x-axis? i need that instead of `12` in image which will be `2021-07-12`

Answer (score 0):

If `DateValue` is already in `datetime64[ns]` format, you can format x axis with:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)
```

The `interval = 1` parameter sets the interval between ticks, 1 day in this case. `'%Y-%m-%d'` is the format of labels: *year-month-day*. The optional `rotation = 90` parameter sets the rotation of the labels, in order to improve readibility.

### Complete Code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as md


DFPlot_T = pd.read_csv(r'data/data.csv')
DFPlot_T['DateValue'] = pd.to_datetime(DFPlot_T['DateValue'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
DFPlot_T['DCID'] = DFPlot_T['DCID'].astype(str)
DFPlot_T['AUC'] = DFPlot_T['AUC'].astype(np.float32)

tDFPlot = DFPlot_T.pivot_table(index='DateValue', columns='DCID',values='AUC', aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(tDFPlot)
ax.legend(labels = tDFPlot.columns, frameon = True)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(md.DayLocator(interval = 1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(md.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.setp(ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation = 90)

plt.show()
```

[image]